# How do I enter HTML tags in a TLD description of a tag?

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsp, taglib, eclipse-wtp

Here's an excerpt from one of my TLD's:

```xml
<attribute>
    <description>
        Possible values:
        1 - just &lt; a&gt;;
        2 - structured with &lt; ul&gt; &lt; li&gt; e &lt; a&gt;;
    </description>
    <name>type</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
</attribute>
```

When editing JSP's in Eclipse, if I look at the attribute description, the line

```xml
1 - just &lt; a&gt;;
```

is correctly rendered like this: `1 - just < a>;`.
But as soon as I remove the spaces in between the entity and the HTML tag name, as in

```xml
1 - just &lt;a&gt;;
```

the HTML tag disappears: `1 - just ;`.

Is this an Eclipse bug or should I write that documentation in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap it into CDATA like this

```xml
<![CDATA[1 - just &lt;a&gt;;]]>
```

as angel brackets are escaped they will be shown in the description.